# How can I change the style of an element when the classlist.add is on another element?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the size of an image when a button is clicked. I have following code:

HTML:

```
<img id="pizzaImage" src="img/pizza.png" alt="pizza">
```

JS:

```
var pizzaImage = document.getElementById('pizzaImage');
Button.onclick = function () {
    pizzaImage.classList.add('changeSize');
};
```

CSS:  (how the .changeSize should look like:)

```
img {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: have you changed img in your css to .changeSize ?

Comment: No I just used img since I don't know how to connect .changeSize and img

Comment: What does the image html look like?

Comment: Doing `img` in your CSS effects every img element,.  I assume you just want  `.changeSize { width: 20%; }` instead

Comment: Please give us your HTML as well, a [MCVE] would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[classList.add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) adds a class to the element. So `img.classList.add('changeSize');` adds the class `changeSize` to the image that you have selected, making the HTML for it look something like:

```html
<img src="URL" class="changeSize" />
```

To make the image grow bigger with that class, you can use the CSS selector `img.changeSize`

The final code could look something like this:

```js
document.querySelector("#changeImgSizeBtn").addEventListener('click', function () {
    var img = document.querySelector("#imgID");
    img.classList.add('changeSize');
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 150px;
}

img.changeSize {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/FrVmtJl.jpg" alt="cat img" id="imgID" />
<br />
<button id="changeImgSizeBtn">Change image size</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
Button.onclick = function () {
var img= document.getElementById('yourImgId');
if(img && img.style) {
    img.classList.add("newStyle");
}
};
```

the html for the image would be:

```
<img src="src" id="yourImgId"/>
```

Add this CSS as well:

```
.newStyle {
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but the thing is, it is for a school assignment and I need to separate the style and the JS

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a .changeSize class to your css:

```
.changeSize {
  width: 50%;
}
```

OR

```
img.changeSize {
  width: 50%;
}
```